# Use PHP Variable as Email Destination in SES

Tags: php, sdk, amazon-web-services

I'm wanting to use a php variable as the destination email for Amazon SES using the aws php sdk... the following are the relevant lines of code

```
$email = new AmazonSES();

$recip = array("ToAddresses"=>"$email");
$message = array("Subject.Data"=>"Welcome to Weather Warnings","Body.Text.Data"=>"tester");
$email->send_email("me@mydomain.com",$recip, $message);
```

my error is.... the line where the recip variable is set is line 31

Catchable fatal error: Object of class AmazonSES could not be converted to string in /home/websites/wxwarn/customer/register.php on line 31

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$email is type of AmazonSES, so it can't be a email Adresse
you have to use an another var for the adress

hi im not at home and can't look in my code but i think you have to type:

```
$email_array = array("test@test.com","test@test.net");
$recip = array("ToAddresses"=>"$email_array");
```

look here:

http://www.alexkorn.com/blog/2011/04/sending-email-aws-php-with-amazonses/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with AmazonSES, but it is an object and not a string, so you'll have to do something like `$recip = array("ToAddresses"=>$email->getEmail());`

If you were to create the __toString() magic method within the AmazonSES object, and have it return the email address (assuming it's a property of that object), I think what you have would work.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
require_once('ses.php');
$ses = new SimpleEmailService('accessKey', 'secretKey');
$m = new SimpleEmailServiceMessage();
$m->addTo('addressee@example.com');
$m->setFrom('Name <yourmail@example.com>');
$m->setSubject('You have got Email!');
$m->setMessageFromString('Your message');
$ses->sendEmail($m);
```

You can get ses.php from http://www.orderingdisorder.com/aws/ses/